# Doing a deep unrar of an archive using the unrar command in Linux

Tags: linux, unrar

I use the following command to unrar all files in a rar-acrhive to a directory

```
unrar x -ep -y archive.rar folder
```

It works great and it ignores the directory structure inside the archive which is just what I want.

How do I make it unrar all rar files inside the archive aswell if there are any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `find folder -name "*.rar" -exec unrar ... "{}" folder \;`

The `"{}"` gets replaced with the name of the archive that `find` found (`unrar` will be called once per match). The `\;` tells `find` the end of the command to `exec`ute.

Replace `...` with the options you want.

You can run that in a loop to do it until no archives are left:

```
while $(find folder -name "*.rar") != "" ; do
    find folder -name "*.rar" -exec unrar ... "{}" folder \;
done
```

It's not extremely efficient if your archives are huge. For huge archives, you may want to cache the result of the first `find` and use that in the loop instead of searching again.

Comment: How would I modify the command so after it extracted the archive it deletes it using rm?

Comment: Add another `-exec`: `... \; -exec rm "{}" \;`